# Delphi: checking selection in Tree View

Tags: delphi, select, treeview

There is a Tree View with 2 levels of items. I need to add a text of all selected "sub" (level 1) items into a Memo.

```
for i := 0 to pred(TreeView1.Items.count) do 
if (TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Selected) and (TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Level=1)
   then 
       begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Text)
       end;
```

But how to add all the "sub" items at once without their checking (selected or not) if their parent (level 0) is selected? E.g. I select the 3 items with the level 0 and their children are added into the Memo.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only get level 1 nodes which have a selected parent:

```
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  Sub: TTreeNode;
begin
  Node := TreeView.Items.GetFirstNode;
  while Node <> nil do
  begin
    if Node.Selected then
    begin
      Sub := Node.GetFirstChild;
      while Sub <> nil do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Sub.Text);
        Sub := Sub.GetNextSibling;
      end;
    end;
    Node := Node.GetNextSibling;
  end;
end;
```

**Update due to comment:**

Get level 1 nodes which have a selected parent, or are selected themselves:

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to TreeView.Items.Count - 1 do
    with TreeView.Items[I] do
      if (Level = 1) and (Selected or Parent.Selected) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Text);
end;
```

Comment: Could you complement the code? I need to add Sub.Text if a child is selected too. Not only parents as in your code. Thanks!

Comment: No need in the second code snippet for checking `Assigned(Parent)` like David H commented in his answer. But this presumtion requires _Complete boolean evaluation {$B}_ set to False, which should always be the case anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are looking for all selected nodes which have a parent node.  The easiest way to do that is as follows:

```
procedure EnumerateSelectedNonTopLevelItems(TreeView: TTreeView; List: TStrings);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  for Node in TreeView.Items do
    if Node.Selected and Assigned(Node.Parent) then
      List.Add(Node.Text);
end;
```

This routine will give you nodes at levels 2, 3, 4 etc.  Since you only have level 0 and level 1 this is fine. If you really did need the nodes that are direct descendants of top-level nodes then you can modify the test like this:

```
if Node.Selected and Assigned(Node.Parent) and not Assigned(Node.Parent.Parent) then
```

Comment: Thanks! But it does not work for parents :( Only children are added.

Comment: @maxfax I thought you only wanted children added.

Comment: It seems I don't fully understand what you want, but the fact remains that testing whether or not `Parent` is assigned is a useful technique. The `Level` property of `TTreeNode` simply walks the `Parent` chain counting how many parents there are.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the answer and the comment!